# Apache2 reverse proxy strips my custom header

Tags: django, apache, reverse-proxy, custom-headers

For my REST API, I am trying to pass a custom header `X-APP-ID` through an apache2 reverse proxy to the application hosting the API, however, it seems like apache2 is stripping away the header. It doesn't arrive at the application. Why is that?

Here is my apache2 config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName $SERVER_NAME
    ServerAlias $SERVER_ALIASES

    # Make sure requests are rewritten to use https://
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$SERVER_ALIASES [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$SERVER_NAME
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         https://$SERVER_NAME/$1 [L,R,NE]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    <Directory />
        Require all granted
        SSLRequireSSL
    </Directory>

    SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256

    # Enable SSL (disabling weak/vulnerable protocols)
    SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
    SSLHonorCipherOrder On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$SERVER_NAME/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/$SERVER_NAME/privkey.pem

   # Logging
   LogLevel warn
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

   # Static files
   Alias /static/ [redacted]
   Alias favicon.ico [redacted]

   # If the URL mentions favicon, but is not acutally pointing to a file
   # location, rewrite the url to point to the favicon file
   RewriteCond  %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule  .*favicon\.ico$        [redacted] [L]

   ProxyPass /static/ !
   ProxyPass /media/ !
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8000/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8000/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    # Rewrite request to use SSL
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/.well-known
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://$SERVER_NAME/$1 [NC,R,L]

    ServerName $SERVER_NAME
    ServerAlias $SERVER_ALIASES

    # Logging
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

    # Location for Let's Encrypt to read and write files
    Alias /.well-known /var/www/html/.well-known

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are you testing whether the header is arriving in your application? `request.META['HTTP_X_APP_ID']`?

Comment: Yup... That is what works when testing directly, but causes KeyError when behind apache reverse proxy

Comment: Well, actually `request.META['X-APP-ID']`

Comment: If it's an HTTP header then Django adds an `HTTP_` prefix to the name. See the [`HttpRequest.META`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) docs.

Comment: You are right. Just confirmed it by using curl to make a request to local dev environment. That rewrite doesn't happen when I make requests from my tests. In that case, I can only find `request.META['X-APP-ID']`, not `request.META['HTTP_X_APP_ID']`. That is another problem then though. Thanks for the assistance

Comment: [As in the examples in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/testing/tools/#making-requests), you should use `HTTP_X_APP_ID` in your unit test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Django converts HTTP header to keys in `request.META`, it converts all characters to uppercase, replaces hyphens with underscores, and adds an `HTTP_` prefix.

Therefore you should access the `X-APP-ID` HTTP header by using `request.META['HTTP_X_APP_ID']`.